# Boost Locale Segmentation fault in debug mode

Tags: c++, debugging, boost

For some reason only in debug mode (with flags -g3) I have a segmentation fault with Boost Locale format function.

```
// at ../../source/EntryPoint/Application.cpp:110
logInfo("sdfsdf");
```

which internally without any transformations uses `boost::locale::format`

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff3a893c3 in std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff3a893c3 in std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
#1  0x0000000000d8392b in boost::locale::details::formattible<char>::write<std::string> (output=..., ptr=0x7fffffffd340)
    at /usr/include/boost/locale/format.hpp:92
#2  0x0000000000d837b6 in boost::locale::details::operator<< (out=..., fmt=...)
    at /usr/include/boost/locale/format.hpp:78
#3  0x0000000000d8319e in boost::locale::basic_format<char>::format_output (
    this=0x7fffffffd410, out=..., sformat="[{1} | {2}]: ({3}, {4})")
    at /usr/include/boost/locale/format.hpp:395
#4  0x0000000000d82b45 in boost::locale::basic_format<char>::write (
    this=0x7fffffffd410, out=...) at /usr/include/boost/locale/format.hpp:269
#5  0x0000000000d8277f in boost::locale::basic_format<char>::str (
    this=0x7fffffffd410, loc=...) at /usr/include/boost/locale/format.hpp:254
#6  0x0000000000d823eb in Uni::Logging::Private::Formatter::_format<std::string&, std::string&, char const*&, int const&> (
    this=0x135afa0 <Uni::Logging::Private::Formatter::get()::_instance>, 
    message="[{1} | {2}]: ({3}, {4})") at /opt/Uni/source/Logging/format.hpp:30
#7  0x0000000000d8221b in Uni::Logging::Private::Formatter::format<std::string&, std::string&, char const*&, int const&> (message="[{1} | {2}]: ({3}, {4})")
    at /opt/Uni/source/Logging/format.hpp:19
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---

#8  0x0000000000d8210e in Uni::Logging::format<std::string&, std::string&, char const*&, int const&> (message="[{1} | {2}]: ({3}, {4})")
    at /opt/Uni/source/Logging/format.hpp:77

#9  0x0000000000e465a3 in Uni::Logging::SimpleLogger::log<>(int const&, char const*, int const&, std::string const&) (
    this=0x135b048 <_ZL30Uni_Logging_globalSimpleLogger>, 
    severity=@0x7fffffffd76c: 2, 
    notifiedFilePath=0x103bcd8 "../../source/EntryPoint/Application.cpp", 
    notifiedLineNumber=@0x7fffffffd768: 110, message="sdfsdf")
    at /opt/Uni/source/Logging/SimpleLogger.hpp:49
#10 0x0000000000e8f753 in FsiSimulation::EntryPoint::ApplicationPrivateImplementation::ApplicationPrivateImplementation (this=0x13662d0, in=0x7fffffffd820, 
    argc_=@0x7fffffffd81c: 1, argv_=0x7fffffffd938)
    at ../../source/EntryPoint/Application.cpp:110
#11 0x0000000000e8b72b in FsiSimulation::EntryPoint::Application::Application (
    this=0x7fffffffd820, argc=@0x7fffffffd81c: 1, argv=0x7fffffffd938)
    at ../../source/EntryPoint/Application.cpp:158
#12 0x0000000000e8b517 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffd938)
    at ../../source/EntryPoint/main.cpp:7
```

Once again with the same code I don't have any segmentation faults in release mode. Any ideas how to track the problem?

Comment: Without seeing any code, it is hard to tell. It might be the code *before* the log call, it might be the log call itself. Try debugging and/or removing code (e.g. code before the log or the log call itself).

Comment: Might be a memory error that is caused by something unrelated to that specific statement. Ideas to track such errors include (1) avoiding manual new/delete (assuming no malloc/free here), (2) use the relevant compiler sanitize options (with gcc that would be `-fsanitize=address`, same for leak and undefined), (3) use the debug versions of the libraries (-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG and possibly -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG_PEDANTIC) or (4) use valgrind. All are very well documented.